# Выполнение последовательных cmd команд

Tags: java, cmd

Нужно открыть cmd.exe, выполнить color 1, tree, после color 2, tree  и т.д.
При помощи .bat файла это сделать легко, но как это сделать в джаве я без понятия. Использовал ProcessBuilder, но я не разобрался как его заставить выполнять команды **последовательно** (он выполняет только первую, а дальше всё ломается и перестаёт работать)

Пытался это провернуть вот таким кусочком кода:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("cmd.exe", "/c", "start color 1 tree color 2 tree");
                try {
                    pb.start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

Comment: А зачем делать в чем, если бат немного проще?

Comment: Батник менее удобен в обращении. Лучше, чтобы код сам генерировал команду.